# List available CmdLets in Package Manager Console

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, powershell-cmdlet

In the package manager console, is it possible to get a list of available cmdlets?

For example, I installed the Entity Framework package and I want to play around with migrations.  I know the commands `Enable-Migrations`, `Add-Migration`, and `Update-Database`, however I want to play with rollbacks but I didn't know the cmdlet to call.

I just want a way to list all available cmdlets in the current context, and if possible a short description of what each does.

edit:

I know how to do a rollback, it was just a story to explain why getting a list of cmdlets would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet
```

You can use:

```
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Get-Help | select name,synopsis | fl
```

to get your description of what the cmdlet does .However, piping to Get-Help seems very slow. There might be a better way of getting the synopsis than calling Get-Help.

Comment: Small proviso: `Get-Command` may list Cmdlets that are "there" but not installed and therefore not runnable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211097